# Django Admin Panel Filtering - Apply Changes on Specific Items

Tags: django, django-models

I have used [**django-admin-sortable2**](https://django-admin-sortable2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) for sorting items.
**Items** model have a field of **category**. I wanted to sort items that have the same **category**.

```py
class Ordering(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(
        "Item",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    main_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("main_order", )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.title

    def reorder(self):
        ordered_list = []
        for order, item in enumerate(Ordering.objects.all(), 1):
            item.main_order = order
            ordered_list.append(item)
        MainPageCoupons.objects.bulk_update(
            objs=ordered_list,
            fields=["main_order", "coupon"]
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.reorder()
```

Is it possible in Django Admin Panel to change a field values for items that have the same value for specific field like **category**?